# Globally mocking data using Vue test utils

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, jestjs, vue-component, vue-test-utils

I have a component in Vue which contains an img tag where the value of src is coming from props.

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <img src="some url">
  </div>
</template>
```

Similarly, this img tag is present in many of my components. For mocking it globally, I made a jest.init.js file where my code goes something like this

```js
import VueTestUtils from "@vue/test-utils";
    
VueTestUtils.config.mocks["img"] =  {src: "rytui"};
```

But it is not working. How should I do it?

Answer (score 0):

some where. You need add `setupFiles` config in your `jest.config.js` like this

```
{
  setupFiles: ["<rootDir>/jest.init.js"],
}
```